# Parse JSON - Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to consume a Rest WebService...

My JSON response structure is:

```
"page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/9Hj2bqi955SvTa5zj7uZs6sic29.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "",
      "release_date": "2015-03-15",
      "genre_ids": [
        99
      ],
      "id": 441580,
      "original_title": "The Jinx: The Life and Deaths of Robert Durst Season 1 Chapter 6: What the Hell Did I Do?",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "The Jinx: The Life and Deaths of Robert Durst Season 1 Chapter 6: What the Hell Did I Do?",
      "backdrop_path": "/3br0Rt90AkaqiwVBZVvVUYD1juQ.jpg",
      "popularity": 1,
      "vote_count": 1,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 10
    }
],
  "total_results": 307211,
  "total_pages": 15361
}
```

I'm trying to get Page and Array of results...but page(paginationCount) and results(jsonArray) variable are nil after parse.

There's my code:

```
 Alamofire.request(ConstantHelper.kUrlDiscoverMovies, method: .get, parameters: ["api_key": ConstantHelper.kApiKey, "certification" : average, "sort_by" : "vote_average.desc" ]).validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let repoJSON = response.result.value as? JSON {
                        let jsonArray = repoJSON["results"] as? NSMutableArray
                        for item in jsonArray! {
                            guard let movie = Movie(json: item as! JSON) else
                            {
                                print("Issue deserializing model")
                                return
                            }
                            listMovies.append(movie)
                        }
                        if let paginationCount = repoJSON["total_pages"] as? String {
                            completion(listMovies, Int(paginationCount)!, nil)
                        }
                        else {
                            completion(listMovies, 0, nil)
                        }
                    }
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(nil, 0, error as NSError?)
                    break
                }
        }
```

Comment: After parse? Where? Inside the success closure, does it works?

Comment: Inside the success closure...  let paginationCount is nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what type `JSON` is,

but the value for key `results` is `[[String:Any]]`, **never** `NSMutableArray`

```
let jsonArray = repoJSON["results"] as? [[String:Any]]
```

and the value for key `total_pages` is `Int` not `String` (there are no double quotes)

```
if let paginationCount = repoJSON["total_pages"] as? Int {
    completion(listMovies, paginationCount, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily parse json using some native Swift method( no need to use alarmofire ) , you can just use the function , if you have a post request , using some post parameters.

PS : a just is a list of tag value , the tag is a String in most cases and the value could be of type anyObject or even a list or a dictionary. For that you need to adapt the data you get from the server to the variables that you have initialised.

```
func parseMyJSon(_ username: String, password: String) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myurlHere")!) // if you have a http please enable the http connection
    request.httpMethod = "POST" // if you have a get request just change it to get 
    // the post parameters
    let postString = "user_name=\(username)&password=\(password)"
    // Get the request :(get the json)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")

            // Do something

            return
        }
        print("the data we have got from the server : \(data!)")
        // Do Something 
        // think about casting your data to NSDictionnary<String,anyObject> in your case or NSDictionnary<String,[String]> // if your values contains a list of Strings 
    })

    task.resume()
}
```